# When do I need MSVCRT redistributables ?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation

I've built a MFC application in Visual studio 2010 and I'm scratching my head about including the redistributals in the installer.

The application is statically linked, so I should not need the redistributables, its selfcontained, right ?

Comment: You mean the application links statically against the MFC libraries, right? Then no, you don't need to include them.

Comment: Since VS2010 you do NOT strictlyneed the redist for msvcp10.dll or msvcr10.dll. I am not sure about mfc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an an easy way to test if you need the redistributable:

- Install a clean Windows 7 on a VirtualBox (or even better Windows XP SP 2, because it doesn't have the basic stuff you would expect)
- Run your software on this VirtualBox

If it doesn't work, you probably need to include the redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be OK but I would install on your intended target platforms and see if it works, if not then you would need to add more dlls or add as a pre-requisite to install the VC resdistributable before installing your app.

Although you may have included the MFC dlls, the Visual C runtime may be different on your target OS so you may still need to include the VC redistributable with you app.

MSDN link about doing the above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx and walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293575.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Any time you statically link a DLL or redistributable, you do not need to redistribute it. That's the core difference between static and dynamic linking.

It'll actually embed the parts you use (or the whole thing, depends) into your application. By redistributing your app, you are, in effect, redistributing its dependencies as well.

Note that you can't always use static linking and it doesn't always make sense to use it even when you can.